# Matlab Meanfreq function with Freqrange

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

[image]

Using the built in function in matlab Meanfreq to calculate the mean frequency of my signal, which is recorded with sensors that have an upper and lower reliable range (70kHz to 500 kHz).

According to the help (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/meanfreq.html#d117e104641) I should be able to specify this reliable range, but when I do this the value MeanFreq returns is outside this range (0.176 kHz) which is clearly not correct.

Anyone know any tips or tricks?

TIA

The code I use w/o the Freqrange is:

```
Fs = 1e6;
figure()
meanfreq(signal, Fs)
```

Then with the Freqrange I have

```
freqrange = [70,500];
Fs = 1e6;
figure()
meanfreq(signal, Fs, freqrange)
```

If I try

```
freqrange = [7e4, 5e5];
```

I get the error:

```
> Error using psdparserange>parseTime (line 103) The frequency range
> must be within the range of F for the specified input.
```

Edit - Trying

```
Fs = 1e6;
figure()
meanfreq(signal, Fs)

figure()
meanfreq(signal,freqrange)
```

Produces a load of errors.

```
Error using meanfreq
Expected input number 1, Pxx, to be nonnegative.

Error in psdparserange>parsePSD (line 121)
validateattributes(Pxx,{'numeric'},{'2d','nonnegative'}, funcName,'Pxx',1);

Error in psdparserange (line 40)
  [Pxx, F, Frange, rbw] = parsePSD(funcName, varargin{1:min(n,3)});

Error in meanfreq (line 63)
[Pxx, F, Frange, rbw, extraArgs, status] = psdparserange('meanfreq', kaiserBeta, varargin{:});

Error in Main_analysis_Fullsignal (line 30)
meanfreq(signal,freqrange)
```

Comment: Interesting, can you show us the figure which is generated by the `meanfreq` function?

Comment: Added in to question :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out the mean frequency should be indicated by a dotted line, which in this case is hard against the y axis because it's so low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was a compataility issue - once I started using the 2019b version of matlab instead of 2017a I had no problem.